# How can I convert an input string that uses 'cultural' number formatting into something JavaScript can understand?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my ASP.Net web application, I allow the user to enter a value for the weight of a product. The user can be anywhere in the world (I have users from the US, France, GB, China, etc).

They enter the weight in a number of ways, including:

Using 100000.99 as an example
100,000.99
100 000,99
100'000.99

You see where I am going with this. I am looking for a way to 'cleanse' this input, and format it in such a way that it will be (forgive my ignorance) 'normal'.

Any ideas on how to do this? Or frameworks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use UI decorators and validators to allow user of each culture input and see numbers formatted for his culture. Then you would able to know which culture is used and handle it correctly. Also you should allow user to select another culture in case you detect it incorrectly.

Please see [this link](http://madskristensen.net/post/get-language-and-country-from-a-browser-in-aspnet) to see how to determine user culture and language